# Analogy electric circuit and magnetic circuit - Power

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism

Here are a table which do the analogy between electric circuit and magnetic circuit. Nevertheless, there is no analogy with power dissipation …

[image]

Nevertheless, It is said that in a transformer with an air gap, the Energy is concentrated into the air gap… This is where the reluctance is maximal as the permeability is lower. If we consider the flux constant as the air gap is small. Then we can Apply the relation P = R*Flux ? What do you think ?

Thank You very much !

Comment: And where would the power be dissipated?

Comment: I did an error.… You re right ! There is no power dissipated. But how can you demonstrate with the above formulas that the Energy is concentrated into the the transformer air gap ?

Comment: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-physics/chapter/magnetic-fields-and-maxwell-revisited/

Comment: http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Workshop/advice/coils/gap/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much !